# how can I receive a list of UsierIDs to insert at a time in stored procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
for (int n = 0; n < scoreDocs.Length; ++n)
{
    doc = new Document();
    ScoreDoc sd = scoreDocs[n];
    float score = sd.Score;
    int docId = sd.Doc;
    doc = searcher.Doc(docId);
    string userId = doc.GetField("userID").StringValue;
    UserID id = new UserID();
    id.user_ID = Convert.ToInt32(userId);
    QueryUsers.Add(id);
}
```

I want to send this List of Id s to Mysql DB , so how can I receive there in my sql Stored procedure ? please writ Stored procedure thanks

Comment: Your question is: Can you do the work for me?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this examples, it will help you :

- [JDBC CallableStatement – Stored Procedure IN parameter example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-in-parameter-example/)
- [Calling Stored Procedures in JDBC Programs](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26251&seqNum=6)